# Python list.remove changes the original list

Tags: python, list

When I tried the following codes in Python, I realized changing one list will change the other list too. Could anyone explain why? I am writing a for loop using list.remove, so I need to keep the original list unchanged. Thanks!

```
list1=list(range(1,11))
list2=list1
list1.remove(1)
print(list2)
# the result is [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

list1=list(range(1,11))
list2=list1
list2.remove(1)
print(list1)
# the result is [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: Briefly: there is no "other" list.

Comment: `list2 = list1` is just a new reference. It's not a new list. Do something like `list2 = list1[:]` to create a new copy

Comment: Thanks very much both!